# Hbase table export to Hive

Tags: hive, migration, hbase

Hello :) I am preparing to move the entire data of 1 hbase table to hive. The size of the table is very large (500Terabytes)

As a result of the search, there is hbase export, but only supports data movement between hbase and hbase (files dropped in hdfs are not plain text, so hive cannot read them immediately)
Also, hive's hbase handler cannot be used because hbase is a remote cluster and various security policies.

It would be nice if INSERT INTO syntax was supported like Hive to Hive, but I am looking for another way. Is there a good way to separate each colume of Hbase table by comma and drop it to hdfs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ExportSnapshot tool to move data from Hbase to HDFS on another cluster, e.g.,

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot MySnapshot -copy-to hdfs://yourserver:8020/hbase_root_dir -mappers 16
```

Check [this](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/hbase-data-access/content/export-to-another-cluster.html) out for more details.

Comment: Thank you for response! But, data moved on another hdfs cluster is written by Hbase format(ImmutableBytesWritable) so cannot be read via hive